# Complex analysis: contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

Evaluate by contour integral:

$$\int_0^1{ dx\over (x^2-x^3)^\frac 13}$$

Should I go for some kind of substitution so that the limit changes to $0$ to $\pi/2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a dumbbell contour $C$ about the branch cut $z \in [0,1]$.  That is, two small circular segments about the branch points, and an upper and lower path connecting them above and below the real axis, respectively, as illustrated below:

[image]

We consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \, f(z) = i 2 \pi \text{Res}_{z=0} \left [\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \right ]$$

where

$$f(z) = z^{-2/3} (1-z)^{-1/3}$$

and the term on the right in the former equation is the residue at infinity.  This residue may be computed by seeing that

$$\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{(z-1)^{-1/3}}{z}$$

so that

$$\text{Res}_{z=0} \left [\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \right ] = (-1)^{-1/3}$$

I will elaborate on this in a bit.

Now, we define

$$z^{-2/3} = e^{-(2/3) \log{z}}$$

such that $\arg{z} \in [-\pi,\pi)$.  This definition is a result of the original branch cut of this factor being $(-\infty,0]$.  Further define

$$(1-z)^{-1/3} = e^{-(1/3) \log{(1-z)}}$$

such that $\arg{(1-z)} \in [0,2\pi)$.  This definition is a result of the original branch cut of this factor being $[1,\infty)$.

To summarize, on the lines above and below the real axis, $z=x \in [0,1]$ and therefore $\arg{z} = 0$.  On the line above the real axis, however, $\arg{(1-z)} = 2 \pi$.  Therefore above the real axis,  $z^{-2/3} (1-z)^{-1/3} =  x^{-2/3} (1-x)^{-1/3} e^{-i 2 \pi/3}$  Below the real axis,  $z^{-2/3} (1-z)^{-1/3} =  x^{-2/3} (1-x)^{-1/3}$ because there, $\arg{(1-z)} = 0$.

Further, it should be clear that the integrals about the small circular arcs of radius $\epsilon$ around the branch points vanish as $\epsilon^{1/3}$.

Therefore, we may write

$$\left ( 1-e^{-i 2 \pi/3}\right) \int_0^1 dx \: x^{-2/3} (1-x)^{-1/3} = i 2 \pi (-1)^{-1/3}$$

Because that residue was calculated from the $1-z$ term, then $-1=e^{i \pi}$ and we have

$$\int_0^1 dx \: x^{-2/3} (1-x)^{-1/3} = i 2 \pi \frac{e^{-i \pi/3}}{1-e^{-i 2 \pi/3}} = \frac{\pi}{\sin{(\pi/3)}} = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: In the very first step should the residue at infinity should it not be $ {1\over z} f({1\over z})$ instead of $ {1\over z^2}f({1\over z}) $ ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: no.

Comment: I really like this solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way without contour integration.
$$I = \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{(x^2-x^3)^{1/3}} = \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{1/3}}$$
Let $x=\sin^2(a)$. We then get that
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{2 \sin(a) \cos(a) da}{\sin^{4/3}(a) \cos^{2/3}(a)} = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{-1/3}(a) \cos^{1/3}(a) da = \beta(1/3,2/3) = \dfrac{2 \pi}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: But not really a response to the problem.  You could go directly from  to the $\int_0^1 {x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}}dx$ to the Beta function, since that is another way to define the Beta function.  So a re-phrasing of the problem would be: Prove by contour integration that $\mathrm{B}(1/3,2/3) = 2\pi/\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\large\tt\mbox{Just another complex contour integration}}$:

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}^{1/3}}}
> =\int_{0}^{1}\pars{{1 \over x} - 1}^{2/3}\,{\dd x \over 1 - x}
> =\int_{\infty}^{1}{\pars{x - 1}^{2/3} \over 1 - 1/x}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{x - 1}^{2/3} \over \pars{x - 1}x}\,\dd x
> =\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2/3} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
> =2\pi\ic\,{\expo{2\pi\ic/3} \over -1}
> -\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{2/3}\expo{4\pi\ic/3} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-2\pi\ic\,\expo{2\pi\ic/3} + \expo{4\pi\ic/3}
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2/3} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}^{1/3}}}
=\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2/3} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
=-2\pi\ic\,{\expo{2\pi\ic/3} \over 1 - \expo{4\pi\ic/3}}
=\pi\,{-2\ic \over \expo{-2\pi\ic/3} - \expo{2\pi\ic/3}}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over \sin\pars{2\pi/3}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}^{1/3}}
> ={2\pi \over \root{3}}} \approx {\tt 3.6276}
> $$