# Calculating integral with branch cut.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

I'm learning how to calculate integrals with branch points using branch cut. For example:
$$I=a\int_{\xi_{1}}^{\xi_{2}}\frac{d\xi}{(1+\xi^{2})\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left(E-U_{0}\xi^{2}\right)}}$$
where $\xi_{1}$, $\xi_{2}$ is branch points.
I've choosed contour like this:
[image]

So, by using residue theorem (and changing sings that metion [here](http://www.math.odu.edu/~jhh/ch45.PDF))

$$I=2\pi i[Res(\infty)-Res(i)-Res(-i)]$$
Obviously
$$Res(\infty)=0$$
$$Res(i)=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left(E+U_{0}\right)}}$$
$$Res(-i)=-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left(E+U_{0}\right)}}$$

So I have a mistake somewhere because integral vanishes. The answer would be correct if there would be the minus sign before Res(i). I am totally confused by it. I will be grateful if you could tell me where my mistake, or give any links.

Comment: What contour are you using for the residue theorem? Where have you put the branch cut?

Comment: Your contour is not really a contour but an illustration of a cut (or the complement of a cut, I don't know).  You need to illustrate the path of integration here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371742/complex-analysis-contour-integration/371887#371887) for a similar analysis.

I would rescale the integral as follows:

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{U_0}} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dz}{[1+(E/U_0) z^2] \sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

To consider this integral, consider the function

$$f(z) = (1-z)^{-1/2} (1+z)^{-1/2} = e^{-(1/2) \log{(1-z)}} e^{-(1/2) \log{(1+z)}}$$

The contour we choose is a dumbbell contour that encircles the chosen branch cut between $[-1,1]$.  Individually, however, the branch cuts were $[1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1]$, respectively.  Thus, $\arg{(1-z)} \in [0,2 \pi)$ and $\arg{(1+z)} \in [-\pi,\pi)$.  Thus, while we may set $\arg{(1+z)} = 0$ on the contour segments above and below the real line, we must have that $\arg{(1-z)} = 0$ below the real line, and $\arg{(1-z)} = 2 \pi$ above the real line.

Above the real axis, then

$$f(z) = (1-z^2)^{-1/2}$$

Below, however,

$$f(z) = (1-z^2)^{-1/2} e^{-i (1/2) 2 \pi} = - (1-z^2)^{-1/2}$$

so that

$$\oint_C  \frac{dz}{[1+(E/U_0) z^2] \sqrt{1-z^2}} = 2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dz}{[1+(E/U_0) z^2] \sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

You are correct that the residue at infinity is zero.  The residues at $z=\pm i \sqrt{(U_0/E)}$ do not cancel because the factor $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$ takes on different signs above and below the branch cut.  Therefore, the residues add.

Putting this all together, I get the value of your original integral as

$$\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}} \frac{a \pi}{\sqrt{E+U_0}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is hidden in the square root which should be defined and treated carefully.

For example, take a point $A$ on the real axis between $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ very close to $\xi_1$, define the square root to be positive at $A$. Consider $A$ as being on the upper side of the branch cut. Now, when we make a counterclockwise tour around $\xi_1$, the argument of the expression under square root will change by $2\pi$, hence the whole square root will be multiplied by $e^{2\pi i/2}=-1$. Therefore, the residues at $\pm i$ will contribute with opposite signs.

Or, more correctly, the residues appear with the same sign but the *function itself* changes the sign: it is real and positive for purely imaginary $\xi$ between $0$ and $i$ and real negative for  purely imaginary $\xi$ between $-i$ and $0$.

Hope this is understandable.