# Argument range for branch cut of $[-1,1]$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

I read somewhere on this site that for a branch cut between $(-\infty, 0]$, the range of values for $\arg(z)$ is $[-\pi,\pi]$, while for a branch cut between $[0,\infty)$, the range of values is $[0,2\pi)$. Why is this so? Is this just a definition, or is there some mathematical reasoning to it? Does this apply to branch cuts along the imaginary axis? Also, for a branch cut that crosses the origin, such as $[-1,1]$ for $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, what should the approach be?

Edit: the question on stackexchange I was referring to is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371742/complex-analysis-contour-integration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ${\rm arg}$ function is multiple valued on $\dot{\mathbb C}$. In order to obtain a well defined and continuous (even smooth) real valued function on a slightly restricted domain one then makes the branch cuts. If the cut is made along the negative real axis one then defines
$${\rm Arg}(z):={\rm the}\bigl({\rm arg}(z)\>\cap\>]{-\pi},\pi[\>\bigr)$$
as *principal value* of the argument, and if the cut is made along the positive real axis one can take
$$\phi(z):={\rm the}\bigl({\rm arg}(z)\>\cap\>]0,2\pi[\>\bigr)$$
as smooth real representant of the argument. In both cases the chosen function jumps by $2\pi$ when you cross the cut. It would be pointless to make a cut along the negative real axis and then choosing $\>]0,2\pi[\>$ as range of the argument.

The cut along $[-1,1]$ is of no help for the argument function, but in other cases it is. The function $$f(z):=\sqrt{z^2-1}\qquad(?)$$
is double valued for all $z\ne\pm1$. But if you make a cut along $[-1,1]$ you can single out the branch that is $\>= +z+o(1)$ for  $|z|\to\infty $, and will never get into trouble, i.e., obtain a single valued function $f$ defined on all of ${\mathbb C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

Comment: The cut $[-1,1]$ always seemed nebulous to me.  I prefer to view it as a result of overlapping cuts.  For example, the cuts from $-1$ to $\infty$ and $1$ to $\infty$ coalesce to form an "effective" cut from $[-1,1]$.  Similarly, the cuts from $-1$ to $-\infty$ and $1$ to $-\infty$ also coalesce to form an "effective" cut from $[-1,1]$.  But those pairs of cuts are distinct and, in my opinion, clarify better the arguments of $z+1$ and $z-1$.  I'd like to hear your thoughts on this whenever you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Branch cuts occasionally refer to the following two *different* concepts, which your question seems to mix together:

- A maximal subset of $\Bbb C$ on which a function can be defined while still being holomorphic (or at least continuous), e.g. $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ for $z^{1/2}$.
- A subset of $\Bbb C$ on which a function $\arg(z)$ (which satisfies certain properties, see below) can be defined.

The former ones can lie basically everywhere in the complex plane (see the examples [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchCut.html)). However, they do not necessarily provide appropriate domains for defining $\arg(z)$, as is evident from your $[-1,1]$-example.

The function $\arg:C\to\Bbb R$ can only be defined on **simply connected** sets $C\subset \Bbb C$ which do **not contain the origin**. Usually, it is also required that $C$ is *open* and *connected*, which then is called a *domain*. Given such a domain $C$, the function $\arg(z)$ is uniquely determined up to an additive constant $2\pi k,k\in\Bbb Z$, e.g. by the following requirements:

- $\arg(z)$ is continuous on $C$,
- $|z|\exp(i \arg(z))=z$ for all $z\in C$.

So given an appropriate branch cut, you do not have much choice on how to choose $\arg(z)$. The proof of this usually involves [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number).

---

**Examples**

- Choosing $C=\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ gives the range of $\arg(z)$ to be $[-\pi+2\pi k,\pi+2\pi k]$ for a $k\in\Bbb Z$ of your choice. Choosing $k=0$ gives the usual range $[-\pi,\pi]$.
- The following spiral branch cut can give $\arg(z)$ a range of $(-\infty,2\pi k)$ for a $k\in \Bbb Z$ of your choice.

[image]

- $C=\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected, hence there does not exist a function $\arg(z)$ on it with the requried properties.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first understand what the purpose of branch cuts are. It originates at the origin. The value of $\, \arg(0) \,$ is undefined, but it is worse than that. If you start at a point
$\,z\,$ and loop around the origin one or more times and end up
at the same point $\,z\,$, then the value of $\,\arg(z)\,$
varies monotonically continuously and ends up differing by a
multiple of $\,2\pi\,$ from its original value, assuming no
branch cut is encountered.

This kind of multi-valued behavior happens for $\, \sqrt{z} \,$ as well. One practical solution is to prevent looping around the origin using branch cuts. The two branch cuts you mention both perform this function well. But, a branch cut that crosses the origin **and** does not go to infinity does **not** perform this function, and hence useless for its intended purpose.

Comment: Hi, I’m afraid my question still hasn’t been answered – I do understand the concept of multi-valued functions and hence the purpose of the branch cut to infinity. However, I don’t understand when to restrict the ranges to -pi to pi or 0 to 2pi, considering they encapsulate the same range of arguments.

Comment: It isn't a matter of restricting ranges. The range of a function is what it is. Changing a function changes its range. In the case of branch cuts, the range is forced on us. When the branch cut is $[0,\infty)$ then $\arg(z)$ continuously goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ as $z$ goes around the origin. You could choose any multiple of $2\pi$ to start with instead of $0$ but then, by continuity the range is forced.

Comment: @Somos **value of arg(z) changes by a multiple of 2$\pi$** . What does it mean in mathematical terms?

Comment: @MeetPatel Thanks for that comment! I have added a bit more explanation in my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Somos  I think it has to do something with limit of function. If it is then please explain it in terms of limit of function.